# Can I use netsh Command on Windows IoT, installed on Raspberry Pi 2 with WiFi adapter?

Tags: raspberry-pi, netsh, hotspot, windows-iot-core-10

I want to use Raspberry pi as the WiFi Repeater, Pi needs to get connected to the WiFi and as well as it needs to work as a hotspot. Is it possible in Windows IoT, if not which OS Can i Use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can use netsh on Windows IoT, but you could write an app that connects to WiFi using [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.WiFi) APIs, then sets up the hotspot using [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.networkoperators.networkoperatortetheringmanager) APIs.

Answer (score 0):

[Netsh is supported on Windows IoT core.](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/commandlineutils)

Make sure your [WiFi adapter](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Docs/HardwareCompatList.htm#WiFi-Dongles) is capable of starting a SoftAP.

[Here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/docs/internetconnectionsharingiotcorenov2015) is the tutorial you can follow.